# how to secure my login user id and passwords specially for facebook

Tags: javascript, cookies, ip-spoofing, facebook

i think they hack me with facebook  cookies.

i dont get what exactly is going on with me. every time i get the login notification from another ip location.i want to secure my cookies and i wanted to get the ip address of the person who ever login me with my email id.

i want to secure my all logins

i dont even get the ip and dont know how to secure myself.

if someone can helped  me in this i wll be thankful.

God bless you, please help me i am in trouble from some days.

Answer (score 1):

[Basic steps to securing your Facebook account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlzXtX4BpGk):

1. Use a strong password
2. Link to a mobile device
3. Enable HTTPS
4. Enable login notifications
5. Enable login approvals
6. Check active sessions for suspicious activity

Comment: i did this all. bt nothing help me

Comment: Change your password on your email linked to your account as well.

Comment: Your system might be compromised. Re-install and protect it better.

Comment: +1 but I'd add: Do not used the same password for all accounts, and in particular, make your email hacker-proof:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/make-your-email-hacker-proof.html